# How can I get a list of the databases on a SQL Server Instance without Admin?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get a list of the databases that are stored in a SQL server instance. I need to do so with minimal privilliges (i.e. I merely have permissions to read them). If necessary, I could accept getting back just the list of databases that the user has permission to view.

I am trying to avoid calls to the **sp_databases** stored procedure, as it doesn't return *any* values for users who are not admins.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Assaf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even guests can read from `sys.databases`:

```
select name from sys.databases
```

Should give you a list of databases on the server that are visible to you.

You can make databases visible by creating a "user mapping" in the "Login Properties" dialog. Members of various server roles can see all databases, like "sysadmin" and "bulkadmin".